# как получить значение в строке

Tags: python, mysql

форумчане, столкнулся с такой проблемой что при функции `cursor.fetchone()` мне выводит в терминал следующую фразу - `"{'warns': 1}"`, а мне нужно просто `"1"`, как это можно реализовать без смены библиотеки?

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host=config.MYSQL_HOST, user=config.MYSQL_USER, password=config.MYSQL_PASSWD, database=config.MYSQL_DB, charset=config.MYSQL_CHARSET, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    with connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            checkwarns = "SELECT `warns` FROM `users` WHERE `userid`=%s"
            cursor.execute(checkwarns, (message.reply_to_message.from_user.id))
        connection.commit()
        await message.reply(cursor.fetchone())
```

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. 
Но мне кажется такое решение:
```
cursor.execute(sql_command)
results = cursor.fetchall()
```
а в свою очередь result можно крутить вертеть.

Comment: суть в том, что мне надо обычное значение `1`, а мне выводит `{'warns': 1}`. А что по поводу вашего ответа, это просто изменение переменных и функции, которая будет копировать полностью всю таблицу и передавать ее.

Comment: Ну например `cursor.fetchone()['warns']`

Comment: да, сработало, спасибо вам, держите плюсик